# Google Maps JavaScript API - Toggle Route Visibility Instead of Clearing It

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, routes, toggle, visibility

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API to display driving routes on a map.

I have this code that will clear the route from the map entirely:

```
directionsDisplayD.setDirections({routes: []});
```

Is there a way to instead just toggle its visibility?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `map` property of the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) object to `null` to hide the directions. Set it back to your `map` object to re-display the directions.

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("btn"), 'click', function(evt) {
    if (directionsDisplay.getMap() != null) directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    else directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: "New York, NY",
    destination: "Trenton, NJ",
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="toggle" />
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```